# Overlay line plot of function onto a grid of numbers

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, overlay

I have a simple table, laid out using `Grid`:

```
Module[{n = 25},
 Grid[
  Table[RandomInteger[{1, 5}], {i, n}, {j, n}]
 ]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Consider each table entry as a Cartesian coordinate `{i,j}`, with the bottom left entry corresponding to `{1,1}` and the top right to `{n,n}`. I would like to overlay a continuous plotted line (minus plot axes) displaying the curve `f[x_] := 1/x` (I have used `x` as the variable to emphasise that I am after a smooth continuous curve).

What I'm after - and please excuse my awful drawing skills - is something like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to do it, despite there being somewhat similar questions already answered. Suggestions?

Comment: What did you try and didn't work? Which one is the similar answer and why does that not provide a solution for you? What should be the scaling between the table index and the plot coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = 25;
t = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 5}], {i, n}, {j, n}];

Plot[1/x, {x, -1, 6},
 PlotStyle -> Red,
 PlotRange -> {{-1, n + 1}, {-1, n + 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1,
 Prolog -> {Table[
    Text[t[[i, j]], {i, j}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}
    ]
   }
 ]
```

[image]